# How to make sure a web view always loads a fresh copy of the page when using react-navigation with React Native / Web View?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview, react-navigation

I am working on React Native App that uses Web Views to display web pages from a particular website. There is no API involved here, so it's just the main category url's of the web page being used as tabs using React Navigation. Each tab loads the links on that page as sub pages.

**Requirement**
The parent website uses a custom analytics solution that tracks user activity and thus the website requires every page to be loaded fresh when users go back or forward to make sure it is registered as a new view of the page. The React Native App currently can not do this as React Navigation saves old visited pages and does not trigger this analytics script when users go back.

It is possible to do a manual reload using useFocusEffect or other similar solutions but that does not work due to some URL's being redirected to another at load time causing navigation stack to have wrong URL when you manually try to do a reload based on URL's on navigation state. This basically causes a loop where navigation gets stuck.

**Problem**
I need a solution where the navigation stack does not cache or save any state except for the actual url loaded on Web View and it load it back when you navigate back.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have a Webview inside each Tab Navigator Screen.
If you want to reload the screen each time you come back to the tab, you might want to check the [unmountOnBlur](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#unmountonblur) props for the TabNavigator.

This will remount the WebView each time you navigate back. If you want to keep the url where the user navigated, you'll need to store it in Context/Redux or in the parent component